# SwiftUI not very responsive to hover events

Tags: macos, list, hover, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a list where I have 200 or 300 elements, and I want to change the color of the text on a hover event. But the app starts to show a delay on the hover events. Check the example code below:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0...1000, id:\.self) {index in
                    Element()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct Element: View {
    @State private var hover = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Not a fast hover!")
          .foregroundColor(hover ? Color.blue : Color.white)
          .onHover {_ in self.hover.toggle()}
    }
}
```

[image]

UPDATE:

This seems to improve the responsiveness. Also if I change the background instead of the foreground color, the code is also more responsive.

```swift
struct Element: View {
    @State private var hover = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("Not a fast hover!").foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            Text("Not a fast hover!").opacity(hover ? 0 : 1).foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
        .frame(width: 200)
        .onHover {_ in self.hover.toggle()}
    }
}
```

Comment: What else have you tried? Using 1000 views in a `VStack` really isn't something mot anyone would do in a version 1.0 framework. For instance, assuming that there's something similar going on to the limitations of a List - have you tried grouping things?

Comment: I have a list with possibly more than 10.000 items. But Currently the code starts to choke at 100 (probably because each item has multiple Text() components). I tried grouping yeah, but did not worked.

Comment: Two thoughts. First, there is a limitation of 10 items in a List. The workaround is to use groups. Look at the 5th hint here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/swiftui-tips-and-tricks (2) While Lists are meant to be analogous to a UITableView - just more declarative and easier to code - remember that we are in the *very* early days of SwiftUI. No matter *how* you want to show 10,000 views, even with reusable rows, I'd be pretty sure you will run into issues with various things - including modifiers performing better than others. How does something like this perform in UIKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use a List component instead of a VStack.